# C# dynamic List to send to sql stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dynamicparameters

I have a List<T> in my c# code. What I want is that I have an api called Employee/GetAllEmployees.
Request parameter is

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "pageSize": 0,
  "search": "string",
  "filterBy": [{
    "key": "idEmployee",
    "value": ["3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"]
  }, {
    "key": "firstName",
    "value": ["abc", "def"]
  }, {
    "key": "mode",
    "value": [1, 2]
  }],
  "orderBy": [{
    "key": "lastName",
    "value": "asc"
  }, {
    "key": "firstName",
    "value": "desc"
  }]
}
```

The problem is that I want to send to the stored procedure dynamic type depends on the coming request.
Is there a way to handle such scenario, and how??
I can create user defined table type in the sql and put this type as request params in the stored procedure, but what about dynamic type?

I have tried to make different list in the request model.
I created List<int, int> for the integer columns in the datatable, then I created List<string, string> for the string columns in the datatable and so on. So for example, if i want to filter for the date values, i need to create List for this specific type

Comment: anything containing multiple tables will need to go as DataTable. you will need to have

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing OData and/or GraphQL, consider those wheels first.

Comment: @JeroenMostert no I'm not reinverting these. I just want to optimize my code and not writing too much interfaces and business and dao.